# iOS. Add object to NSMutableArray in valueForKeyPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

If I have an `NSMutableArray` that looks like this:

```
 self.securityQuestionsMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 // This is how I would add an object or objects to a `NSMutableArray`
 //[self.securityQuestionsMutableArray addObject:@""];

 {
    answer = "";
    description = "ID Number";
    displayText = "ID Number";
    fieldName = IDNumber;
    secuityQuestionId = 1;
},
    {
    answer = "";
    description = "Test Question";
    displayText = "Test Question";
    fieldName = "Test Questionr";
    secuityQuestionId = 2;
}
```

How can I add an object or objects in valueForKeyPath@"answer" valueForKeyPath `NSMutableArray`
to my existing `NSMutableArray`

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want to add a dictionary object to array or something else? Consider it revising.

Comment: If you see answer = ""; in the array is empty. I want to populate that with values by adding objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the values of individual *NSMutableDictionary* objects key-value pair like this

> [[self.securityQuestionsMutableArray objectAtIndex:index] setValue:@"new Value" forKeyPath:@"answer"];

Here *index* will point to the specific object inside array. But remember all the objects inside the array should be of mutable dictionary type. If you use *NSDictionary* object, this will crash.